# Passing Arguments Through Threads in Windows Form C++/CLI

Tags: multithreading, winforms, arguments, c++-cli

I´m really having a lot of trouble to do something that is probably quite simple. Basically, I´m trying to write a Windows Form C++/CLI program to read an arduino stream from a serial port and, at least initially, add each value to a listBox. The Arduino Code is ok and it gives me a string every 2 seconds, and when I debug the Windows Form with a breakpoint, I can see the value of the string variable "Message" coming in just fine. But I ran into this "thread" problem, and I understand I have to create a different thread to update the listBox... Ok. Now, what I can´t find a way to do is to pass that "message" string to the function "UpdateList". I´ve seen a lot of things about passing an object, a class, and so on... But can´t manage to fit it in my code. Could anyone help?

The full code is as follows:

```
#pragma once

namespace ArduComm {
using namespace System;
using namespace System::ComponentModel;
using namespace System::Collections;
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
using namespace System::Data;
using namespace System::Drawing;
using namespace System::Threading;

public ref class MyForm : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
{
public:
    MyForm(void)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

protected:
    ~MyForm()
    {
        if (components)
        {
            delete components;
        }
    }

private: System::IO::Ports::SerialPort^  Arduino;
private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  StartButton;
private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  StopButton;
private: System::Windows::Forms::ListBox^  ListBox;
private: System::ComponentModel::IContainer^  components;

#pragma region Windows Form Designer generated code

    void InitializeComponent(void)
    {
        this->components = (gcnew System::ComponentModel::Container());
        this->Arduino = (gcnew System::IO::Ports::SerialPort(this->components));
        this->StartButton = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
        this->StopButton = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
        this->ListBox = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::ListBox());
        this->SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // Arduino
        // 
        this->Arduino->PortName = L"COM3";
        this->Arduino->DataReceived += gcnew System::IO::Ports::SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(this, &MyForm::ArduinoDataReceived);
        // 
        // StartButton
        // 
        this->StartButton->Location = System::Drawing::Point(12, 12);
        this->StartButton->Name = L"StartButton";
        this->StartButton->Size = System::Drawing::Size(75, 23);
        this->StartButton->TabIndex = 3;
        this->StartButton->Text = L"Start";
        this->StartButton->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this->StartButton->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &MyForm::StartReadingSerial);
        // 
        // StopButton
        // 
        this->StopButton->Location = System::Drawing::Point(12, 41);
        this->StopButton->Name = L"StopButton";
        this->StopButton->Size = System::Drawing::Size(75, 23);
        this->StopButton->TabIndex = 4;
        this->StopButton->Text = L"Stop";
        this->StopButton->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this->StopButton->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &MyForm::StopReadingSerial);
        // 
        // ListBox
        // 
        this->ListBox->FormattingEnabled = true;
        this->ListBox->Location = System::Drawing::Point(117, 12);
        this->ListBox->Name = L"ListBox";
        this->ListBox->Size = System::Drawing::Size(273, 277);
        this->ListBox->TabIndex = 5;
        // 
        // MyForm
        // 
        this->AutoScaleDimensions = System::Drawing::SizeF(6, 13);
        this->AutoScaleMode = System::Windows::Forms::AutoScaleMode::Font;
        this->ClientSize = System::Drawing::Size(409, 303);
        this->Controls->Add(this->ListBox);
        this->Controls->Add(this->StopButton);
        this->Controls->Add(this->StartButton);
        this->Name = L"MyForm";
        this->Text = L"ArduComm";
        this->ResumeLayout(false);

    }
#pragma endregion

/* My functions */


private: System::Void UpdateList() {
    ListBox->Items->Add("xxx");
}

private: System::Void InvokeThread()    {
    this->Invoke(gcnew MethodInvoker(this, &MyForm::UpdateList));
}

private: System::Void ArduinoDataReceived(System::Object^ sender, System::IO::Ports::SerialDataReceivedEventArgs^ e) {
    String^ Message;
    Message = Arduino -> ReadLine();
    Thread^ oThread = gcnew Thread(gcnew ThreadStart(this, &MyForm::InvokeThread));
    oThread->Start();
}

private: System::Void StartReadingSerial(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
    this->Arduino->Open();
}

private: System::Void StopReadingSerial(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
    this->Arduino->Close();
}

};
}
```

Any help would be very much appreciated...

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do *not* start a thread.  The SerialPort::DataReceived event handler already runs on a worker thread, adding yet another thread accomplishes nothing.  You need to write a method that you can invoke from the event handler, it should look like this:

```
    void UpdateList(String^ message) {
        ListBox->Items->Add(message);
    }
```

Now you need to declare a delegate that's compatible with this method, a crucial step you overlooked and what got you stuck:

```
    delegate void UpdateListDelegate(String^ Message);
```

Or you can use the built-in `Action<String^>` generic type.  Now you can invoke it from your event handler.  Very important to use BeginInvoke(), using Invoke() has very high odds of deadlocking your program when you close the serial port:

```
    System::Void Arduino_DataReceived(System::Object^  sender, System::IO::Ports::SerialDataReceivedEventArgs^  e) {
        String^ message = Arduino->ReadLine();
        this->BeginInvoke(gcnew UpdateListDelegate(this, &MyForm::UpdateList), message);
    }
```

Comment: Wow Mr. @HansPassant. The code you gave me works perfectly, although I do not fully understand it. The reason why I started a thread in the first place is that, after trying the simplest way (add message to the ListBox inside the DataReceived function), I was getting an error message saying "Invalid operation between threads ... control accessed from a thread ... not the one in which it was created", and every solution I could find told me I should start a new thread.

Comment: To be honest, all this "thread" and "delegate" and "invoke" stuff is completely new to me. I guess it´s time to dig a little deeper in these!! Very much appreciate for taking your time for this help!